# Configuring the proper join column in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I have two models, which associate with each other through a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.

```
class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :stages, association_foreign_key: :stage_number
end

class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :bands
end
```

Assume both tables have an id field, and that stage has a `stage_name` field.

They're related to each other through a table called `bands_stages`, with a schema that looks similar to this:

```
create_table :bands_stages, id: false do |t|
    t.integer :band_id
    t.integer :stage_number
end
```

My intention is to use Rails Admin to allow us to modify certain fields on the `Stage`, but every time that runs, I get an SQL error doing so:

> column `stages.id` does not exist

It seems that Rails Admin is picking the wrong column by default to join on.  How would I inform Rails Admin that I want it to join on a column that actually *exists* in my join table?

Note that I can't actually make use of the ID in the `stages` table.  The intention is that only ten stages exist at any given time, denoted by their stage number, but every band can visit each stage.  Since an ID would automatically increment, it seems to be safer and more explicit to its intent to leverage the more concrete `:stage_number` field instead.

Comment: The error you're seeing means you don't have an `id` column on `stages`. Did you also `create_table ... id: false` for stages? Any reason why you don't just add `stage_id` to `bands_groups`, and then reference the `stage_number` from there? That would make your association less hacky.

Comment: @JoshBrody: There is a reason to not use the ID; as a business rule, there are only 10 stages that will ever exist. However, it's expected that each band can visit each stage.  The ID won't give me what I need, especially when testing, since I will refer to the stage by its stage number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure that it's not a problem of rails admin but habtm association.
To make habtm use the right column in sql primary key must be specified for stage model and foreign key for association.
And it is the only way to make it works right.

```
class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = "stage_number"

    has_and_belongs_to_many :bands, foreign_key: :stage_number
end
```

But I think the best way is to use joint model and has_many/belongs_to because for has_many/belongs_to it's possible to set any column to be used as primary key via :primary_key option.

```
class BandStageLink < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "bands_stages"

    belongs_to :band
    belongs_to :stage, foreign_key: :stage_number, primary_key: :stage_number
end
class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :band_stage_links
    has_many :stages, through: :band_stage_links, foreign_key: :stage_number
end
class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :band_stage_links, primary_key: :stage_number, foreign_key: :stage_number
    has_many :bands, through: :band_stage_links
end
```

**Update:** Note that in this case there is still no need to specify any primary keys for stage table. For instance my migration is:

```
class CreateStageBandTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :bands_stages, id: false do |t|
            t.integer :band_id
            t.integer :stage_number
        end

        create_table :bands do |t|
            t.string :name
        end

        create_table :stages, id: false do |t|
            t.integer :stage_number
            t.string :name
        end
    end
end
```

I tested both cases for rails 4.2.5 and everything works just fine.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that it was something so simple.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** - I did mis-understand the primary key bit, I think the desire was to tell Rails to use different attribute as PK, which should be less problematic than re-purposing the auto-increment-by-default PK ID. In that case, the `Stage` model should include `self.primary_key = "stage_number"`, and the rest of the details at the bottom of this answer relating to HABTM alongside that. Of course has-many-through would still be my preferred solution here.

I think there's a bigger problem with the models and approach, than Rails Admin.

If I understand what you're trying to do, then you'd also need to turn off auto-increment for the primary key in `stages` table, to hold arbitrary numbers (representing stage numbers) as primary key IDs. It could end badly very quickly, so I'd advise against it.

If the data is genuinely static (10 stages ever), you could even keep it as a constant in the `Band` model and scrap `Stage` completely (unless there's more there), e.g.

```
class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
  POSSIBLE_STAGES = [1, 2, ...]
  validates :stage, inclusion: { in: POSSIBLE_STAGES, message: "%{value} is not a stage we know of!" }
end
```

For a table-based approach, I would suggest has-many-through, it'll save you a lot of pain in the future (even if you don't need additional attributes on the join table, things like nested forms are a little easier to work with than in HABTM). Something like this:

```
class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :stages, through :events
  # band details go into this model
end
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :band
  belongs_to :stage
  # you could later add attributes here, such as date/time of event, used_capacity, attendee rating, and
  # even validations such as no more than X bands on any given stage at the same time etc.
end
class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :bands, through :events
  # stage number/details go into this model
end
```

The migration for that could look something like this:

```
create_table :bands do |t|
  t.string :bandname
  # whatever else
end
create_table :events do |t|
  t.belongs_to :band
  t.belongs_to :stage
  # you could add attributes here as well, e.g. t.integer :used_capacity
end
create_table :stages do |t|
  t.integer :number
  t.integer :total_capacity
  # whatever else
end
```

As you can see primary key IDs are not touched here at all, and I would always avoid storing business data in Rails' and databases' plumbing of any sort (which is what I consider IDs to be, they're there to ensure relation/integrity of the data in a relational database, as well as nice and consistent mapping to ActiveRecord - all business data should be beside that, in actual attributes, not plumbing used to connect models).

If you still want HABTM and re-purposing of primary ID, then I think `Stage` should include a `foreign_key` statement to "advertise" itself to the `bands_stages` join table as having a custom key name (in `bands_stages` only), while keeping the `association_foreign_key` on the `Band` end to show what you want to query in the join table to reach the other side. The `stages` table would still utilise `id` though as its primary key, you'd just want to turn off auto-increment with something like `t.integer :id, :options => 'PRIMARY KEY'` (might be dependent on the database flavour - and again, I would advise against this).

Your models would look like this:

```
class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stages, association_foreign_key: "stage_number"
end
class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bands, foreign_key: "stage_number"
end
```

The connection between `bands` and `bands_stages` would be `bands.id = bands_stages.band_id`, for which many `bands_stages.stage_number` would be found, and each would be connected to `stage` via `bands_stages.stage_number = stages.id` (where `stages.id` has been re-purposed to represent business data at a likely future peril).

Answer (score 2):

Change the `association_foreign_key` value to be a string instead of symbol.

```
class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :stages, association_foreign_key: 'stage_number'
end

class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bands, foreign_key: 'stage_number'
end
```